# Find in nested array with compare on last field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection with documents like this one:

```
{
  f1: {
   firstArray: [
     {
      secondArray: [{status: "foo1"}, {status: "foo2"}, {status: "foo3"}]
     }
   ]
  }
}
```

My expected result includes documents that have at least one item in `firstArray`, which is last object `status` on the `secondArray` is included in an input array of values (eg. ["foo3"]).

I don't must use aggregate.

I tried:

```
    {
        "f1.firstArray": {
          $elemMatch: {
            "secondArray.status": {
              $in: ["foo3"],
            },
            otherField: "bar",
          },
        },
      }
```

Comment: Can you add sample documents and the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an aggregation pipeline with `$match` and `$filter`, to keep only documents that their size of matching last items are greater than zero:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {
      $expr: {
        $gt: [
          {$size: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$f1.firstArray",
                cond: {$in: [{$last: "$$this.secondArray.status"}, ["foo3"]]}
              }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FXd-SsVgVWL)

If you know that the `secondArray` have always 3 items you can do:

```
db.collection.find({
  "f1.firstArray": {
    $elemMatch: {
      "secondArray.2.status": {
        $in: ["foo3"]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

But otherwise I don't think you can check only the last item without an aggregaation. The idea is that a regular `find` allows you to write a query that do not use values that are specific for each document. If the size of the array can be different on each document or even on different items on the same document, you need to use an aggregation pipeline

Comment: thanks, but can I avoid to use aggregate?

Comment: Since you want to check only the last one, I don't think you can avoid it